# Why a * does not get replaced in a variable value

Tags: bash, dockerfile

I tried to write a generic Dockerfile and I would like not changed the file names each time the version changes. How is it possible to use a `*` for variable names?

```
ADD ./Trimmomatic-*.zip /tmp/
RUN cd /usr/local ; unzip /tmp/Trimmomatic*.zip
ENV JAR_LOC echo `ls -1 /usr/local/Trimmomatic/trimmomatic-*.jar`
RUN chmod 755 ${JAR_LOC}
RUN ln -s /usr/local/Trimmomatic/trimmomatic-*.jar /usr/local/bin/trimmomatic.jar
RUN rm -rf /tmp/Trimmomatic*.zip
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
Step 12 : ADD ./Trimmomatic-*.zip /tmp/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b0104788f151
Step 13 : RUN cd /usr/local ; unzip /tmp/Trimmomatic*.zip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ffeae9bbd5f6
Step 14 : ENV JAR_LOC echo `ls -1 /usr/local/Trimmomatic/trimmomatic-*.jar`
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e4f836c140ca
Step 15 : RUN chmod 755 ${JAR_LOC}
 ---> Running in 539728a7f13f
chmod: cannot access '755': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'echo': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '`ls': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/Trimmomatic/trimmomatic-*.jar`': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod 755 ${JAR_LOC}' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Why a `*` does not get replaced in variable value

Comment: You just don't use *

Comment: Not knowing docker I'm going to assume because docker isn't a shell and those commands aren't expanded by a shell as wildcards. Same reason you get those "No such file or directory" errors from docker where you tried to run shell commands.